# Deploy revel application on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, go, revel

I am trying to deploy an application in heroku. I am using the revel framework, but (I don't know if it can be a problem) I wasn't using the framework before... but yesterday I move my code into the framework. The web application works locally, but it can't be deployed in heroku.

This is the output when I try "git push heroku master"

```
Counting objects: 46, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Writing objects: 100% (46/46), 135.45 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 46 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Checking Godeps/Godeps.json file.
remote: -----> Using go1.6.3
remote:  !!    Installing package '.' (default)
remote:  !!    
remote:  !!    
remote: -----> Running: godep go install -v -tags heroku .
remote: can't load package: package ndc-console: no buildable Go source files in /tmp/tmp.XI5m2PPe7K/.go/src/ndc-console
remote: godep: go exit status 1
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to ndc-console.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/ndc-console.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ndc-console.git'
```

Any idea what I need to do??
Thank you.

Comment: Build the binary, [allocate and publish a slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs). Deployments done in this way take us about 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can [build a slug locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs), as suggested by @thwd, but this may be a bit tricky if you aren't already building for linux/amd64. (I've never done this myself)

Another option is to use a [build pack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). The official build pack for revel is here: https://github.com/robfig/heroku-buildpack-go-revel but I think it's out of date -- you should fork it and fix it up to your needs. (here's [my version](https://github.com/bejayoharen/heroku-buildpack-go-revel))

Comment: Yes. Using a buildpack was the solution... but I needed to make a new app on heroku and "install" the buildpack in the begining.